# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int\limits_0^1 \ln (1 + e^{nx}) dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I have to find the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \ln (1 + e^{nx}) dx$$

I kept trying to find something that I could use the Squeeze Theorem on, but I didn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the one hand, it's at least $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1\ln(e^{nx})dx=\int_0^1xdx=\frac12$. On the other hand, it's at most $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1\ln(2e^{nx})dx=\frac12+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln 2}{n}\int_0^1dx=\frac12$.

Answer (score 4):

Squeeze theorem works here. For example consider elementary inequalities:
$$
nx = \ln(e^{nx}) \le \ln(1 + e^{nx}) \le \ln(2e^{nx}) = \ln 2 + nx
$$
The lower and upper bound now are easy to integrate and for your sequence $a_n$ you have estimates 
$$
\frac{1}{2} \le a_n \le \frac{\ln 2}{n} + \frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$ln(1+e^{nx})=ln(e^{nx}(1+e^{-nx}))=ln(e^{nx})+ln(1+e^{-nx)}=nx+ln(1+e^{-nx})$.

Therefore $\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1ln(1+e^{nx})dx=\int_0^1(x+\frac{1}{n}ln(1+e^{-nx})dx=1+\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1ln(1+e^{-nx})dx \to 1$, as $n\to \infty$.